# how can i get pandas dataframe from excel in showing datatype?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, google-drive-api

**Environment:**
python 3.8.5
ipython 7.20.0
jupyterlab 3.0.7
ubuntu 20.04 LTS
pandas 1.2.2
openpyxl 3.0.10
googledrive (spreadsheet)

**I'm doing...**

```
import pandas as pd
ef = pd.ExcelFile('myfile.xlsx')  
df = ef.parse(ef.sheet_names[0], headers=None)
display(df)
```

Parsing exported xlsx from google spreadsheet to dataframe.
The spreadsheet's content is following next:

[image: A1 shows 1-1 but actual value is 2022.01.01 00:00:00]

**The Problem**
It always parse A1(=1-1) to **pd.Timestamp(2022.01.01 00:00:00)**.
But I want string value of "1-1".
I think it's origin value already inserted to datetime type.

**I tried**
Most of SO's solve is next.
So i tried that.

```
df1 = ef.parse(ef.sheet_names[0], headers=None)
df1.columns #=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
df = ef.parse(ef.sheet_names[0], headers=None, converters={c:str for c in df1.columns})
display(df.iloc[0][0])
```

But it shows string value but "2022-01-01 00:00:00"

**Constraints**
The spreadsheet's writer(=operator) says to me "I typed exactly 1-1 on the spreadsheet"
And there are many spreadsheet writer.
So they won't input **'1-1** instead of **1-1**, and strictly check it is really inserted string type or datetime type.

And google spreadsheet API (not drive api) returns it's value '1-1', so it works. But that API's quota is too small (60 calls per 1min, and consumes 1 call per 1 sub-spreadsheet). So I must need google drive api and export it.
That's why I can't using spreadsheet API notwithstanding it's actually works.

**hope**
I got xlsx exported file from google drive api like next way.

```
request = _google_drive_client.files().export_media(fileId=file_id,
                                               mimeType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
file = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(file, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
dn = file.getValue()
with open('test.xlsx', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(dn)
```

And my Apple Numbers shows me the information of '1-1' is still alive in that xlsx file.
[image]

So I hope I can find and make '1-1' in python again.

**Question**
Is there any way xlsx file load to python memory that's showing way? (I mean '1-1', not following origin value (datetime type 2022 01 01 00:00:00), or other parsing way)
Or simply I want '1-1' from parsing way.
Help me please!

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood your question right. If you want to know how you can display `1-1` in it's actual state as straight text after exporting it to excel, I think it's best to use pandas with xlwings:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

df = pd.DataFrame([
    (1, "1-1", 8),
    (4, 0, "=1-1")],
    columns=["A", "B", "C"]
    )

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book()
    ws = wb.sheets[0]
    ws.api.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"  # Or instead: ws.range("A1:Z100").number_format = "@"
    ws["A1"].value = df
    wb.save("test.xlsx")
    wb.close()
```

The crucial point is to set the `NumberFormat` or rather `number_format` property before loading the values of `df` into the cells. This ensures that `1-1` appears as straight text.

As a side note: `ws.api.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"` changes the format of the whole sheet to text. If you prefer to change only a certain range, use `ws.range("A1:Z100").number_format = "@"`.
Please also note that xlwings requires an excel installation.

Comment: thank you for idea, that is great for sovling. You understood for my problem, but my working environment is docker so I find another solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not pandas, of course.  The problem is Excel.  Unless told otherwise, it interprets `1-1` as a date.  If you want to override that, start with a single quote: `'1-1`.  The quote won't show, but Excel will treat the cell as a string.

Comment: I agree with that, but In my situation, can't force to workers write that. And I think information of **original data -> showing data** is included xlsx file. Because, in spite of it stored 'Datetime(2022-01-01 00:00:00)' form in excel actually, it shows same form like '1-1' in same file in google spreadsheet and apple numbers. And other saved versions, they shows sometimes 2022-01-01 or 2022.01.01 to same type but they also stored type as datetime and they also same 'Datetime(2022-01-01 00:00:00)'. Because human writer assign other showing format to that cell.

Comment: In this situation, they are basically same data, but It is difference with '1-1' form. So my conclusion is 'the xlsx file' has stored **information of how to they shows** that assigned by file writers. And in this question, I want 'can I access **that information** when parsing pandas?' or other way? (not dataframe parse, just json is also good)

Answer (score 1):

I answer for my own question because I found a answer.

I stop using for pandas dataframe excel parser.

I tried many mimeTypes for googledrive API, finally I dropped odf and xlsx export.

Finally I using 'zip' that makes every sheet to html, and one css file.

I downloaded it zip, and extract, and finally find the html contains the contents it shows exact same with google spreadsheet.

My solution is next:

```
def extract_zip(input_zip):
    input_zip=ZipFile(input_zip)
    return {name: input_zip.read(name) for name in input_zip.namelist()}

def read_json_from_zip_bytearray(file_bytearray):
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
    from zipfile import ZipFile
    
    do = extract_zip(io.BytesIO(file_bytearray))
    
    dw = {k[:-5]:[[row.text for row in columns.find_all('td')] for columns in soup(v).find('table').find_all('tr') if columns.find_all('td')] for k, v in do.items() if k[-5:] == '.html'}
    
    return {k:[singlev for singlev in vv if singlev] for idx, vv in enumerate(v) for k, v in dw.items()}


read_json_from_zip_bytearray(downloaded_bytearray_from_googledrive_api_and_zip_mimetype)

#the value is
{'sheetname1': ['1-1',
   '1-2',
   '1-3',
   '1-4',
   '1-5',
   'other...'],
 'sheetname2': ['2-1', '2-2', '2-3'],
   ...}

 #anyway you can make dataframe with pd.DataFrame() method
```

I appreciate for every answers!

And I hope someone for who using google drive API & parse it keep it's own showing way.